How to disable 'copy all' in KeePass 2?
In KeePass 2 when I right click it opens a menu with the option 'copy all'. Clicking this copies all of the contents of the entry to the clipboard. How do I turn off this option? How do I make it so that 'copy all' does not show up?

That option only shows up in the "Entry View" section, so you could hide that part of the layout by going to View, and deselect "Show Entry View".
That option itself cannot be removed, but you can get close by going to: Tools > Options > Policy, and disable the feature "Copy", and "Copy Whole Entries" as well if needed. This should block all clipboard use if that's what you're looking for?
It only copies the visible text (just like selecting the text with your mouse and copying that), so you might have to be more specific about what your use case is


I want to be able to copy link, but not copy all. Hmm.

@northerner Then just hide the Entry View, right? If you need to edit the UI, you might be able to adjust it with a plugin https://keepass.info/plugins.html . "KeyUIExt" mentions adding options to the Entry context menu, so you may be able to remove them with similar code

I tried unchecking "Copy" and "Copy Whole Entries" but it seems to have no effect as the "copy all" option is still there.
